# VBA SQL returning null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

I'm having a problem running a SQL statement on vba excel, the last 3 Columns are for storing numbers separated by commas, but when executed on excel vba it doesn't display these values, while on other Database programs it does

the code is the following

```vb
Sub obtainColMachs()    
    Dim cnn1 As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset, sqry As String

    Set cnn1 = New ADODB.Connection
        cnn1.ConnectionString = "driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;" & _
        "server=server;uid=user;pwd=password;database=DB;"
        cnn1.ConnectionTimeout = 3
        cnn1.Open

    sqry = "select top 1 m.* from recipe r left join RecipeGroup rg on r.RecipeGroupID = rg.RecipeGroupID " & _
    "left join Matricula m on tonalidad_ID = ParentGroupID *100 + rg.RecipeGroupID where Substring(ColorNo,3,3) = 'ZG5'"

    mrs.Open sqry, cnn1
    Range("A26").CopyFromRecordset mrs

    mrs.Close
    cnn1.Close
End Sub
```

It should return:

[image: Data returned on Database program]

But it only returns:

[image: Data returned in VBA Excel]

Answer (score 1):

You only seem to be returning fields from your `Matricula` table; perhaps the SQL should be:

```
select top 1 m.*, r.*, rg.* from
```

Or better yet, a list of the fields that are actually required and with reference to the table from which they originate, e.g.:

```
select top 1 m.Tonalidad, m.Field2, r.Field3, rg.Field4 etc... from
```